# Rsync: Push certain files to another server without the sub-folders

Tags: directory, rsync

There are similar questions, but I cannot find one that answers what I need. Server A has a bunch of media files on it each one in sub-folders under the main, for example: `/home/user/Summer/` and in that folder are subfolders `2010`, `2011`, `2012` and so on; the files are of the types `.jpg`, `.gif`, and `.png` and I want to push them to another server to this folder `/home/user/pictures`.

The current line I am trying to use is:

```
rsync -avPWr --exclude='*/' --include="*.jpg" --include="*.gif" --include="*.png" --perms --chmod=777 -p /home21/user/Summer/ user@ip:/home/user/pictures
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?